# Pseudo elements cover up .block while animation running

Tags: css, css-animations, pseudo-element

While slide animation running, the pseudo elements cover up the .block div.
I've tried many things to solve it, if i remove the `slide-right-opacity` animation, the `pseudo-elements` will go behind `.block`.

```css
.block {
    position: relative;
    margin: 300px auto 0;
    width: 500px;
    height: 250px;
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, pink, #272727);
    animation-name: slide-right-opacity;
    animation-duration: .5s;
    animation-delay: 0.1s;
    animation-fill-mode: none;
    z-index: 1;
}

 .block:before, .block:after {
    position: absolute;
    left: -2px;
    top: -2px;
    background: linear-gradient(200deg, #fb0094, #0000ff, #00ff00,#ffff00, #ff0000, #fb0094, 
        #0000ff, #00ff00,#ffff00, #ff0000);
    background-size: 400%;
    width: calc(100% + 4px);
    height: calc(100% + 4px);
    animation: steam 20s linear infinite;
    z-index: -1;
}

@keyframes slide-right-opacity {
    0% {
        transform:translateX(200%);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }
}

@keyframes steam {
    0% {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 400% 0;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
}
.block:after {
    filter: blur(50px);
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I recommend posting a [mcve] of the HTML also. That would assist users in testing and finding solutions

Comment: <div class="block"></div>